# What exactly is information change?

Tags: planning

A few companies talk about 'information change' as part of their analytics group, for example here: http://graduates.westpacgroup.com.au/graddetails/business-performance-analytics

What does this mean? I have read about change management but I don't think it would be that. Is information change similar to change management, i.e., is it a structured approach to how information is used?

If anyone could give me a clear description of what this is, and how it benefits a business I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As you suspected, Information Change is not synonymous with Change Management.

Change Management is a defined process for changing the scope of a project: the forms to fill in, the people to inform, etc.

Information Change seems to be the field of studying the impact of changing certain parts of a data set.

Concepts that you can get a peek at in the abstract about [Reasoning about Information Change](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008222603071) like:

> "You know the meaning of a
>   sentence if you know the change it brings about in the information state of anyone
>   who accepts the news conveyed by it", the meaning of a sentence is associated with
>   a function on information states. We will discuss Veltman’s update semantics as
>   a simple example to illustrate the main notions involved. The language of update
>   semantics is a standard propositional modal language.

and

> An update of an information state ᵅ with a sentence p results in a state containing
>   all and only the worlds in ᵅ in which p is true. The result of updating a state ᵅ
>   with a negated sentence is a state containing all worlds in ᵅ that do not survive in
>   ᵅ updated with δ. Conjunction is defined as intersection.

Another glimpse can be seen from the description of this workshop on [Correlated Information Change](http://events.illc.uva.nl/LogiCIC14/index.html).

Of interest to project managers would be the domino-effect that changing one datum can have on the entire set - and this is where Information Change would meet Change Management and Scheduling. :-)